# Write a python function to reverse a sentence that are separated by dot

Tags: python

I am trying to reverse a sentence separated by dots.

Input: `"talking am I. Walking am I"`
Output: `"I am talking. I am walking"`

I am running the following code, but it is giving me different output.

```py
def reversed_string(words):

    words = words.split(' ')
    reverse_words = ' '.join(reversed(words))
    return reverse_words
```

The output I am getting is: `I am walking. I am talking`

Comment: Does this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66713806/19298921

Comment: I don't see how this can be the output.  Why did the period move from `I` to `walking`?

Comment: That's not "a sentence separated by dots".  That's two sentences.  You need to reverse them separately.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a double split, double join. One for the sentences, one for the words:

```
s = "talking am I. Walking am I"

out = '. '.join([' '.join(reversed(x.split()))
                 for x in s.split('.')])
```

Output: `'I am talking. I am Walking'`

*NB. I am not considering case or a potentially final period here, only the core logic, but this can be handled with a bit of pre/post-processing.*

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, what you are doing involves reversal at the *sentence level*, rather than the *string level* as you're currently trying to implement.

What I would recommend is first creating a list `sentences` and then using a `for` loop or a `map` with lambda function if you wanted to be fancy. Simple implementation might look like:

```
    sentences = input_str.split('.')
    reverse_sentences = ''
    for sentence in sentences:
        words = sentence.split(' ')
        reverse_words = ' '.join(reversed(words))
        reverse_sentences += reverse_words
    return reverse_sentences
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution of @mozway, but I wrote this recursive version:

```
def reverse_by_sentence(sentences):
    if '.' not in sentences:
        words = sentences.strip().split(' ')
        reverse_words = ' '.join(reversed(words))
        return reverse_words
    else:
        sentences = [reverse_by_sentence(s) for s in sentences.split('.')]
        return '. '.join(sentences)
    
reverse_by_sentence(input)
Out[19]: 'I am talking. I am Walking'
```

*edit: No longer adds a space at the end*

Comment: This is not really recursive as you can only have one level, this is more a test in disguise. Also requiring to test the presence of the period is not really useful as you will have to read the full string for that. `split` is already doing that: if you have no period then the output is a list with a unique string, idem for `join`, on a list with single string this outputs the string. It's a fun code but not optimal IMO ;)

Comment: NB. I didn't downvote

Comment: No problem, just noticed that it adds a space at the end, so it doesn't actually answer the question...

Comment: I upvoted, because this sort of coding amuses me, and is worth knowing about.

Comment: Writing this as if it is recursive serves no purpose other than making the code confusing.

Comment: I agree, but am leaving the answer as it got one upvote. Plus I kind of like it.